# My app Signup activity (that I made) is not completely visible (cut from bottom) on my device

Tags: android

I made a sign-up activity in android studio with XML and tested it on first genymotion emulator with(S8 Android 7.1). The result was fine. But when I tested that on my Android Device (Samsung Galaxy J1 2016 Android 5.1), the layout is not completely visible, it is stretched from bottom.

I have tried to change the phone layout form 5inches (Pixel) to my smartphone size (4.5inches) but the result are same.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="245dp">

        <EditText
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textColorHint="#fff"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Username" />

        <EditText
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textColorHint="#fff"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Email" />

        <EditText
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textColorHint="#fff"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Password" />

        <EditText
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textColorHint="#fff"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Phone#" />

        <Button
            android:fontFamily="verdana"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style_selector"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:text="Signup"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This the screenshot of the Android Device result:

[image: Layout as rendered on device, Sign Up button is cut off at bottom]

Comment: Sorry about formating, first time asking.

Comment: you have used `android:paddingTop="245dp"` in your LinearLayout. Try using weight to your code to manage the position of EditTexts and Button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `android:paddingTop="245dp"`, change `layout_height` to `wrap_content` and add `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` on the first LinearLayout and it should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

The simpliest solution is to used [Constraint Layout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/)

Here you use a paddingTop to 245dp, all phones doesn't have the same size so it's normal that in certain phone you get the cropped bottom.

Try with ConstraintLayout :)

Answer (score 1):

The way you are making your layout is not good at all. It may look great in one device and be awful in another.

First take a look at these topics:

https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support

But in my own experience `ConstraintLayout` can be not efficient to be used in some cases,  the approach I choose in `LinearLayouts`. It may seems a little complex to use `LinearLayout` in all of your layout parts but it makes it much more flexible.

some times I  face something like this:

```
<LinearLayout 
     <LinearLayout 
     <LinearLayout 
     ....
```

But you know when its done it looks great. Of course you must know how to use some tools like weights etc. so I recommend you to use `LinearLayout` over Relative and don't use hard coded like paddingTop to `245dp.

Answer (score 1):

using too much `paddingTop` with `LinearLayout`for this case is not good,
    android:paddingTop="245dp"
instead you can use `RelativeLayout` with `alignParentBottom="true"` property and rearrange other views by `layout_above` property

Try this XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="245dp">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/email_EditText"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textColorHint="#fff" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email_EditText"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/password_EditText"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textColorHint="#fff" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password_EditText"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/phone_EditText"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textColorHint="#fff" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phone_EditText"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/signUp_Button"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Phone#"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textColorHint="#fff" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signUp_Button"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_style_selector"
        android:fontFamily="verdana"
        android:text="Signup"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="22dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `paddingTop` of the `LinearLayout` you are using is much more than required. Try removing it.

But even then you want the same look, you can try wrapping your layout in a `ScrollView` like this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent">

    <!-- All your Relative layout goes here -->

</ScrollView>
```